# Do a flag (1 or 0) using DAX Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to DAX and i want to do a flag based on the time

the flag column is called "New", to determine whether is it new, Value YTD >0 and Value YTD Past Year is 0 or blank

my table

```
period | product | value YTD | value YTD Past Year |
202201 | Apple | 1000 | 0
202201 | Orange | 1000 | 0
202201 | Durian | 2033 | 100
```

output
table

```
period | product | value YTD | value YTD Past Year | New 
202201 | Apple | 1000 | 0 | 1
202201 | Orange | 1000 | 0 | 1
202201 | Durian | 2033 | 100 | 0
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you have three cases :

| Value YTD | Value YTD Past Year | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| >0 | >0 | 0 |
| >0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | BLANK |

Then, you should be able to create the new calculated column `New` as

```
New =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    [Value YTD] > 0 && [Value YTD Past Year] > 0,
    0,
    [Value YTD] > 0 && [Value YTD Past Year] = 0,
    1,
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! I will need to count the number of 1 and 0 too. I realised i am unable to perform a count. any suggestions?

Comment: To count the number of 1 and 0 you can create new measures. Like `NumberofOnes = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table), Table[New) = 1)`